# My Vue CDN code is not working, my output says {{ name }}

Tags: vue.js, cdn

Below is the code I typed into my editor. I've tried the same with both my brackets and Atom editors and the result is the same.
I just can't get the Vue part of the code to work. I've tried multiple links as well, uncluding the unpkg link. Nothing works.

Here is the code:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="">
    <head>
        <title>Vue JS Learning</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test">
            {{name}}
        </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**script.js**

```
let two = new Vue({
  el : "#test",
  data : {
    name : "Hello"
  }
});
```

The above code does not work. I'm getting {{ name }} as the output.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Your code is working. Are you sure you are using the right path for the script?

Comment: Yes, they're all in the same folder.

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in console? Your code works fine on JSFiddle

Comment: I just recreated the same file in a new folder and it works now. This is crazy!

Answer (score 0):

New to Vue here too.  Based on the script.js file it seems to me that you omitted the 'mount'.

`let two = new Vue({ el : "#test", data : { name : "Hello" } }).mount('#test')`

Make sure that you include a string and (usually) a reference to an 'id' that exists within your HTML.